# MSVS 2015: vector<bool> has no 'data' member

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, std, stdvector

I have the following code that compiles just fine:

```
void foo::bar(const vector<int> arg) {
    int* ptr = arg.data();
    // do something with ptr
}
```

I need to overload this function for `vector<bool>`

```
void foo::bar(const vector<bool> arg) {
    int* ptr = arg.data(); 
    // error C2039: 'data': is not a member ofstd::vector<bool,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
    // do something with ptr
}
```

What is the reason for `vector<bool>` not to have a `data()` member?

Here ([en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)) I did not find somethign specific for `bool` case of `std::vector`.

The code is compiled with MSVS 2015.

Comment: Look up [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual `vector<T>` store data as one contiguous block of `T`'s, so it's possible to return pointer to them as to array.

`vector<bool>` stores several boolean values in 1 byte, so it's not possible to return such a pointer

Answer (score 6):

The whole point of the [`vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) specialisation is that unlike all other vectors, the data in `vector<bool>` does not need to be stored as an array of `bool`. It can be stored more efficiently, by packing multiple bits in a single byte. Because of that, there is no `bool *` that could possibly be returned by a `data()` member.